# Ola Hallengren maintenance solution

Tags: sql-server, index, maintenance, ola-hallengren

When I am executing the below query:

```
EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize
            @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
            @FragmentationLow = NULL,
            @FragmentationMedium = NULL,
            @FragmentationHigh = NULL,
            @UpdateStatistics = 'ALL',
            @OnlyModifiedStatistics = 'Y'
```

I'm getting this error:

> Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure dbo.CommandExecute, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Procedure or function 'CommandExecute' expects parameter '@DatabaseContext', which was not supplied.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Hany

Comment: Are you on the latest version of Ola's scripts?

Comment: Yes, Dec 2020 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely have a version mismatch between the IndexOptimize and CommandExecute procedures.

This is apparent from the error message you posted along with the version control done in a recent version of Ola's IndexOptimize procedure (reading the source code).

I would delete the 4 stored procedures and let his installation script create them anew. Be careful with what database you specify in the script. If you want his script to also re-create the jobs, then specify that in the installation script and delete the current jobs first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your assistant, issue resolved.

Comment: it's also a bug already solved:
https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution/issues/381